# Scipy Curvefit for a Single Variable in an Exponential Function

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

So I have a set of X and Y data that I read in from an output file and then truncate. I'll give a sample of it below just in case anybody wants it as a reference to potentially test my problem (apologies that it is so much)

```
0   16442
4   15222
8   14222
12  12934
16  11837
20  10706
24  9689
28  8844
32  7999
36  7128
40  6547
44  5890
48  5378
52  4838
56  4308
60  4005
64  3587
68  3228
72  2933
76  2610
80  2434
84  2184
88  1951
92  1755
96  1632
100 1441
104 1362
108 1150
112 1095
116 1051
120 991
124 859
128 775
132 727
136 678
140 635
144 610
148 535
152 560
156 510
160 460
164 431
168 407
172 387
176 391
180 362
184 368
188 317
192 317
196 302
200 289
204 259
208 307
212 263
216 262
220 264
224 218
228 220
232 242
236 224
240 198
244 207
248 192
252 207
256 194
260 172
264 167
268 192
272 148
276 187
280 166
284 159
288 143
292 150
296 155
300 160
304 159
308 144
312 128
316 133
320 105
324 120
328 134
332 129
336 117
340 132
344 118
348 137
352 134
356 119
360 121
364 99
368 111
372 95
376 106
380 89
384 104
388 113
392 117
396 114
400 88
404 82
408 78
412 77
416 79
420 84
424 85
428 75
432 76
436 74
440 96
444 65
448 90
452 72
456 74
460 68
464 66
468 76
472 66
476 69
480 63
484 61
488 51
492 60
496 67
500 71
504 54
508 55
512 61
516 49
520 47
524 42
528 48
532 44
536 47
540 43
544 54
548 42
552 39
556 40
560 44
564 41
568 53
572 50
576 43
580 36
584 49
588 35
592 40
596 34
```

This data shows time and tallies, and represent an exponential decay type of trend. All of the data recorded is similar, but there is a single coefficient that changes for each record taken, and so i'm trying to develop a code to then find out what that single coefficient is. The equation i'm using as a fit is:

> Y*((exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL110))) + (X*exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL108)))) + b

The variable that is changing here is Y. Everything else is known. This is the variable I want to fit to (Y). I've done some work in Excel and can say that it is in the high 9000s (this is just going off of memory). Other cases are in the 4000s and 7000s. So it ranges, and that's why I need a code to do it, otherwise I have to manually do it every time, and we have thousands of records that I have to analyze. I wrote a code, but it flatlines and doesn't really provide a fit. I'll supply it below. It also contains all the constants mentioned above, which aren't subject to change.

```
### Section 1 ###
from scipy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


### Section 2 ###
data = np.loadtxt('Ag - Near_7_2026.txt') ### LOAD FILE DATA HERE ###
data_trunc = data[25:len(data)] ### TRUNCATED DATA UP TO 104 SEC ###
TM = data_trunc[:,0] ### TIME MARK ###
TMA = TM + 4 ### CORRECTED TIME ARRAY, ELAPSED TIME ###
Counts = data_trunc[:,1]
Sigma = sqrt([Counts])


### DEFINE PROBLEM CONSTANTS ###
HL110 = 24.6 ### ENDF ACCEPTED HL ###
HL108 = 142.92 ### ENDF ACCEPTED HL ###
b = 1.3333
X = 0.02955 ### FROM MCNP MODEL ###


### Function Handel ###
def func(TMA, Y, X, HL110, HL108, b):
    return Y*((exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL110))) + (X*exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL108)))) + b ### MODEL FUNCTION ###

f = func(TMA, 5000, X, HL110, HL108, b) ### CALLABLE NEEDED FOR CURVE_FIT ###

# Data plotting ###
pyplot.plot(TMA, f, '.b', label = 'data')
pyplot.legend(fontsize = 'large')


### Curve Fitting and plotting ###
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, TMA, f)
pyplot.plot(TMA, func(TMA, *popt), 'r-', label = 'fit')
pyplot.tick_params(labelsize='large')
pyplot.legend(fontsize='large')
pyplot.xlabel('Adjusted Time')
pyplot.ylabel('Counts')
pyplot.show()
```

I've done my best to hopefully comment out most of the code here to help anyone assisting me with understanding what is what. When I was doing this, I used https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html as my reference. (I'm not associated with them or anything, I'm just trying to show my thought process just in case it lends any extra information on where i'm going wrong).

Any help is really appreciated, and I'm available to provide any clarifying information requested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work with few changes. I made a text file using your data, and for the code itself I do not pass the constants to the functions.

[image: plot]

```
### Section 1 ###
from scipy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


### Section 2 ###
#data = np.loadtxt('Ag - Near_7_2026.txt') ### LOAD FILE DATA HERE ###
data = np.loadtxt('temp.dat')
data_trunc = data[25:len(data)] ### TRUNCATED DATA UP TO 104 SEC ###
TM = data_trunc[:,0] ### TIME MARK ###
TMA = TM + 4 ### CORRECTED TIME ARRAY, ELAPSED TIME ###
Counts = data_trunc[:,1]
Sigma = sqrt([Counts])


### DEFINE PROBLEM CONSTANTS ###
HL110 = 24.6 ### ENDF ACCEPTED HL ###
HL108 = 142.92 ### ENDF ACCEPTED HL ###
b = 1.3333
X = 0.02955 ### FROM MCNP MODEL ###


### Function Handel ###
def func(TMA, Y): # no need to pass constants
    return Y*((exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL110))) + (X*exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL108)))) + b ### MODEL FUNCTION ###

# # no need to pass constants
f = func(TMA, 5000) ### CALLABLE NEEDED FOR CURVE_FIT ###

# Data plotting ###
pyplot.plot(TMA, f, '.b', label = 'data')
pyplot.legend(fontsize = 'large')


### Curve Fitting and plotting ###
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, TMA, f)
print('Fitted parameters:', popt)

pyplot.plot(TMA, func(TMA, *popt), 'r-', label = 'fit')
pyplot.tick_params(labelsize='large')
pyplot.legend(fontsize='large')
pyplot.xlabel('Adjusted Time')
pyplot.ylabel('Counts')
pyplot.show()
```

EDIT -- code to solve for Y

```
### Section 1 ###
from scipy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.optimize import minimize_scalar
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np


### Section 2 ###
#data = np.loadtxt('Ag - Near_7_2026.txt') ### LOAD FILE DATA HERE ###
data = np.loadtxt('temp.dat')
data_trunc = data[25:len(data)] ### TRUNCATED DATA UP TO 104 SEC ###
TM = data_trunc[:,0] ### TIME MARK ###
TMA = TM + 4 ### CORRECTED TIME ARRAY, ELAPSED TIME ###
Counts = data_trunc[:,1]
Sigma = sqrt(Counts)


### DEFINE PROBLEM CONSTANTS ###
HL110 = 24.6 ### ENDF ACCEPTED HL ###
HL108 = 142.92 ### ENDF ACCEPTED HL ###
b = 1.3333
X = 0.02955 ### FROM MCNP MODEL ###


### Function Handel ###
def func(TMA, Y): # no need to pass constants
    return Y*((exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL110))) + (X*exp(-TMA*(log(2.)/HL108)))) + b ### MODEL FUNCTION ###

# # no need to pass constants
#f = func(TMA, 5000) ### CALLABLE NEEDED FOR CURVE_FIT ###

# Data plotting ###
pyplot.plot(TMA, Counts, '.b', label = 'data')
pyplot.legend(fontsize = 'large')


### Curve Fitting and plotting ###
popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, TMA, Counts)
print('Fitted parameters:', popt)

pyplot.plot(TMA, func(TMA, *popt), 'r-', label = 'fit')
pyplot.tick_params(labelsize='large')
pyplot.legend(fontsize='large')
pyplot.xlabel('Adjusted Time')
pyplot.ylabel('Counts')
pyplot.show()
```

Comment: My question is how can we determine what the EXACT **Y** value is? In the code I have "5000" as a placeholder, but what about finding which Y gives the closest fit?

Comment: I have added code under a note labeled "EDIT -- code to solve for Y" that does this. I use "Counts" instead of "f". By the way, my background is in nuclear engineering.

Comment: Oh that's awesome! In what regard? And the issue then here is that the covariance it gives is rather high. Forgive me if i'm wrong, but this would want to be minimized, correct? The Y value for the given data set is approximately 5890, when done via an Excel sheet. The Y given by the _solution_ is well over 20,000 with a covariance well over 6000.

Comment: Edit: It is seen that with truncation, the suggested Y value is even lower, by about an order of magnitude.

Comment: In the code I posted, if you replace the fitted value from curve_fit() with "popt=[5890.0]" then (in technical terns)  the plot stinks. Either the data, thePython equation, or the value 5890 is incorrect.